# A list of tag synonyms not proposed in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process, synonym-request

Stack Exchange is a big community with users from different backgrounds. In its each sub-site, tens of thousands of tags are proposed by different users to annotate questions. However, due to the diversity of the human language, it is very likely that same-meaning tags with slightly different forms co-exist in the site (e.g., [pdfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdfjs/info),  [pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdf.js/info)).

Although I have seen a lot of tag synonyms, only part of them are listed in the [officially-curated synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). But the [rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/synonyms) are too **strict**:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms.

With a [synonym-finding algorithm](http://ccywch.github.io/chenchunyang.github.io/publication/seThesaurus.pdf) and a manual check, I found a lot of tag synonyms on Stack Overflow. But due to my reputation score, I can only list them below:

```
ajax-forms --> ajaxform
formsauthentication --> form-authentication
formsauthentication --> forms-authentication
menu-items --> menuitem
jarsign --> jar-signing
typeconverting --> typeconverter
tabbed-view --> tabview
windowsformhost --> windowsformshost
equality-operator --> equals-operator
codesign --> code-signing
log-files --> logfiles
clisp --> common-lisp
data-formats --> dataformat
decimal-format --> decimalformat
googlesigninaccount --> google-account
dynamic-html --> dhtml
checklistbox --> checkedlistbox
subdirectories --> subdirectory
access-point --> apn
inter-process-communicat --> ipc
qwebkit --> qtwebkit
er-diagram --> erd
writablebitmap --> writeablebitmap
square-root --> sqrt
event-listener --> eventlistener
referer --> referrer
keyevent --> keyboard-events
packet-capture --> pcap
oracle-service-bus --> osb
rich-internet-application --> ria
double-buffering --> doublebuffered
system-administration --> sysadmin
multiple-processes --> multiprocess
datetime-parsing --> date-parsing
pdfjs --> pdf.js
entity-sql --> esql
alassetlibrary --> alassetslibrary
multiple-value --> multivalue
json-web-token --> jwt
jeasyui --> jquery-easyui
args --> arguments
typelibrary --> type-library
voicexml --> vxml
routedevent --> routed-events
file-read --> filereader
xmldom --> xmldocument
libwww-perl --> lwp
bll --> business-logic-layer
filebrowse --> file-browser
settings-bundle --> settings.bundle
collaborative --> collaboration
googlesigninapi --> google-signin
gcal --> google-calendar
visual-studio-package --> vspackage
delimited --> delimiter
audiostreamer --> audio-streaming
sql-server-data-tools --> ssdt
appsettings --> application-settings
initializing --> initialization
fulltext-index --> full-text-indexing
date-difference --> datediff
angularjs-google-maps --> angular-google-maps
event-listeners --> eventlistener
self-organizing-maps --> som
cardio --> card.io
numberformatter --> number-formatting
beizer --> bezier
nested-query --> nested-queries
database-link --> dblink
node-streams --> node.js-stream
data-cleansing --> data-cleaning
static-initializer --> static-initialization
sqlite.net --> sqlite-net
web-user-controls --> webusercontrol
cc --> cross-compiling
fpc --> freepascal
data-transfer-objects --> dto
event-viewer --> eventviewer
adobe-native-extensions --> ane
builtin --> built-in
visual-studio-code --> vscode
sharp-architecture --> s#arp-architecture
store --> storage
transparent --> transparency
ipcs --> inter-process-communicat
kernel-extension --> kext
angularjs-ng-if --> angular-ng-if
workflow-services --> workflowservice
last-insert-id --> lastinsertid
webdeploy --> web-deployment
pop-up --> popup
meteor-useraccounts --> meteor-accounts
yo --> yeoman
equivalence --> equivalent
multifile --> multiple-files
angularjs-templates --> angular-template
web-config-transform --> web.config-transform
webusercontrols --> web-user-controls
boost.build --> boost-build
syntaxhighlighter --> syntax-highlighting
rdebug --> ruby-debug
cakephp-model --> cakephp-appmodel
sti --> single-table-inheritance
lostfocus --> lost-focus
hls --> http-live-streaming
intermediate-language --> il
capture-group --> capturing-group
tree-nodes --> treenode
formatted --> formatter
persistent --> persistence
portable-executable --> pe
ivar --> instance-variables
router --> routes
webservices-client --> webservice-client
multiple-file-upload --> multifile-uploader
dynamic-queries --> dynamicquery
va-arg --> varargs
udf --> user-defined-functions
end-of-line --> eol
kvc --> key-value-coding
alwaysontop --> always-on-top
typeconverting --> type-conversion
window-server --> windows-server
sencha-command --> sencha-cmd
location-based-service --> location-services
jtemplates --> jquery-templates
mq --> message-queue
google-authenticator --> google-authentication
azuread --> azure-active-directory
fsm --> finite-state-machine
quality-center --> qc
dimension-reduction --> dimensionality-reduction
uia --> ui-automation
cleditor --> ckeditor
access-point-name --> apn
ane --> air-native-extension
interpreted --> interpreter
abtest --> ab-testing
typedarray --> typed-arrays
deeplink --> deep-linking
elastic-map-reduce --> emr
mongo-java --> mongodb-java
edt --> event-dispatch-thread
collapsable --> collapse
singlepage --> single-page-application
key-events --> keyevent
application-bar --> appbar
blobstorage --> blobstore
multipleselection --> multiple-select
analog-digital-converter --> adc
dynamic-usercontrols --> dynamic-controls
dynamicform --> dynamic-forms
google-closure-libraries --> google-closure-library
poptoviewcontroller --> popviewcontroller
btle --> bluetooth-lowenergy
output-caching --> outputcache
enumerator --> enumeration
angular-filters --> angularjs-filter
boost-jam --> bjam
change-data-capture --> cdc
info-plist --> info.plist
multiple-users --> multi-user
process-control --> pcntl
auto-rotation --> autorotate
global-assembly-cache --> gac
audiorecord --> audio-recording
role-based-access-control --> rbac
rational-team-concert --> rtc
opendocument --> odt
dbproj --> database-project
angularjs-http --> angular-http
angular-module --> angularjs-module
multi-monitor --> multiple-monitors
word-boundaries --> word-boundary
listview-adapter --> listadapter
topic-modeling --> tm
topicmodels --> topic-modeling
administrator --> administration
transactional --> transactions
television --> tv
qsort --> quicksort
jexcelapi --> jxl
angularjs-resource --> angular-resource
builtins --> built-in
pch --> precompiled-headers
filehandle --> file-handling
virtual-hosts --> virtualhost
azure-management-api --> azure-api-management
advertisement --> ads
wmp --> windows-media-player
over-the-air --> ota
lazyload --> lazy-loading
django-caching --> django-cache
dbconnection --> database-connection
speechsynthesizer --> speech-synthesis
numerics --> numerical
disassembly --> disassembling
multiple-languages --> multilanguage
hdd --> hard-drive
emulation --> emulator
xamarin-forms --> xamarin.forms
options-menu --> optionmenu
apn --> apple-push-notifications
angularjs-bootstrap --> angular-bootstrap
angular-controller --> angularjs-controller
mtm --> microsoft-test-manager
systray --> system-tray
uisearchbardisplaycontrol --> uisearchdisplaycontroller
dih --> dataimporthandler
viewhelper --> view-helpers
mpchart --> mpandroidchart
adaptor --> adapter
embedded-ruby --> erb
formhelper --> form-helpers
gwt-platform --> gwtp
templating-engine --> template-engine
hiddenfield --> hidden-field
angularjs-ng-model --> angular-ngmodel
android-internet --> android-intent
embedded-javascript --> ejs
asp.net-compiler --> aspnet-compiler
pyunit --> python-unittest
tvp --> table-valued-parameters
accesscontrolservice --> acs
skimage --> scikit-image
windows-forms-host --> windowsformshost
sessionstorage --> session-storage
validating --> validation
window-messages --> windows-messages
human-computer-interface --> hci
customizing --> customization
mouse-listeners --> mouselistener
routedevents --> routed-events
server-side-includes --> ssi
form-authentication --> forms-authentication
vuejs --> vue.js
routedcommand --> routed-commands
multiple-select --> multi-select
itemsource --> itemssource
virtualfilesystem --> vfs
backbone.js-collections --> backbone-collections
covariant --> covariance
domready --> document-ready
single-instance --> singleinstance
applicationdomain --> appdomain
fab --> floating-action-button
ajaxuploader --> ajax-upload
data-storage --> datastore
django-tests --> django-testing
modified-preorder-tree-t --> mptt
contenttype --> content-type
er-diagrams --> erd
bulkloader --> bulk-load
drop-shadow --> dropshadow
virtual-hosts --> vhosts
rpt --> report
io-completion-ports --> iocp
eventreceiver --> event-receiver
automaton --> automata
maximization --> minimization
django-mailer --> django-email
hextiles --> hexagonal-tiles
complex-event-processing --> cep
event-triggers --> eventtrigger
angular-routing --> angularjs-routing
django-tagging --> django-taggit
minmax --> minimax
winddk --> wdk
distributed-cache --> distributed-caching
charts.js --> chart.js
rte --> rich-text-editor
disassembler --> disassembly
left-recursion --> lr
synchronisation --> synchronization
xmldoc --> xml-documentation
angular-directive --> angularjs-directive
pdfviewer --> pdf-viewer
multi-database --> multiple-databases
keystonejs --> keystone.js
refcounting --> reference-counting
integration-tests --> integration-testing
metatag --> meta-tags
osk --> on-screen-keyboard
virtual-reality --> vr
richtextediting --> rte
tm --> text-mining
data-members --> datamember
linux-containers --> lxc
performance-monitor --> perfmon
bit-masks --> bitmask
normalizing --> normalization
winapp --> windows-applications
facebook-authorization --> facebook-authentication
database-connectivity --> database-connection
rr --> rspec-rails
powermanager --> power-management
log-files --> logfile
tmp --> temp
multiple-projects --> multi-project
fso --> filesystemobject
ios-extensions --> ios-app-extension
scriplets --> scriptlet
gunzip --> gz
webtest --> web-testing
evaluator --> evaluation
ratelimit --> rate-limiting
coords --> coordinates
http-request --> httprequest
communicate --> communication
multi-table --> multiple-tables
application-data --> appdata
interaction --> interactive
vertex-array-object --> vao
migrating --> migration
custom-validators --> customvalidator
rdms --> rdbms
content-delivery-network --> cdn
mvcminiprofiler --> mvc-mini-profiler
schtasks --> scheduled-tasks
jil --> jsonserializer
paginator --> paginate
paginator --> pagination
mongodb-shell --> mongo-shell
command --> cmd
typelib --> type-library
dfs --> depth-first-search
tph --> table-per-hierarchy
```

If you think the pairs are right and have the reputation to propose such tag synonyms, please help me propose them.
If there are any problems with this list, you can edit it or ask me to do it.